# Windows 10 A2DP Sink connection with a one button bluetooth audio device

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, a2dp

I've recently utilised the Windows 10 A2DP audio sink feature (via the UWP app) to get Bluetooth audio from my phone to the computer. On top of that, I also recently obtained a bluetooth turntable for my LPs.

I was attempting to connect my bluetooth turntable to the computer but ran into a snag. Since the turntable is a one-button connecting bluetooth device - where you put the device into a search/pairing mode, it can't select a specific device to connect to nor will it try to connect to a non-audio device (such as a computer since it isn't a default audio bt device). I was wondering if there is a way to spoof or trick such device to connect or force a connection in order to send the audio to the pc and then use the A2DP feature to listen to it. I do get that this seems redundant and I ought to listen directly but this is more of a nice to have type thing.

The turntable device in question is the Audio Technica LP60XBT. As aforementioned, it does have a pairing mode and thus will successfully connect to something like a LG Soundbar or bluetooth headphones that are also in pairing mode.

**TL;DR**: Turntable can't connect to Windows 10 A2DP since it can't pair to it like a normal bluetooth audio output. Is there a way to bypass/force it?

**EDIT:** Best guess from the insights of others and further thought, since the turntable itself is discovering rather being discovered, there wouldn't be a way to establish a connection unless somehow the PC becomes an audio device and start doing a pairing mode type of thing.

Comment: So if you just set your Windows to be discoverable and press the wireless button on the turntable for 2 sec as described in [the manual](https://sea.audio-technica.com/image/catalog/Manual/AT-LP60XBT_UM_162501372_V2_EN_web_190527.pdf), Win Bluetooth doesn't discover it, or does discover it but fails to pair?

Comment: @Peregrino69 It doesn't discover it nor does it pair; however, it will pair automatically with a device like an LG Soundbar that is nearby also looking for BT audio devices. My best guess is that it isn't exactly discoverable but is discovering.

Comment: I think you're right. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mention of a PC in the device manual is:

> PC sound card | LINE | PC sound card’s line input jack
>
> **An audio adapter (sold separately) may be required to connect the RCA audio cable to the line input jack of the PC sound card

AT has published quite a few videos describing how to use Audacity with the device, but I'm not able to find anything that talks about connecting it to PC via Bluetooth. It might be possible using an external USB audio receiver, otherwise the only option appears to be a wired connection.

Comment: Yeah. The only thing I could come up with is that since the turntable itself is discovering rather than being discovered, I can't initiate a connection between the two at all, even with A2DP sink. Potentially if there was a way to set the Bluetooth on my pc to become a dedicated audio device then it could work but I doubt that would even be possible.

Comment: I don't think so either. BT has latency and is subject to interference neither of which affect wire as much, so there probably isn't much demand for such, yet anyway.

Comment: If nobody provides a better answer in a couple of days, please accept mine, or write an answer yourself and accept that one. Unanswered -queue doesn't get purged (at least very often) so questions without accepted answers keep ghosting in there and popping up to fill up the front page for years to come... I've seen several over a decade old...